# Flush rewrite rules when every page gives 500 error?

Tags: rewrite-rules, 500-internal-error

Ok, this is embarrassing. I created an infinite loop on every page using the following rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('.', 'home/', 'top');
```

I have no idea how to undo it, as every page, including settings pages, now give me a 500 error. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: try to rename the file `.htaccess` on the root of the website

Comment: Oh wow, the `.htaccess` file contains the rules themselves! Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the offending rewrite rule manually from the `.htaccess` file, in the web site's root.

Thanks, "mmm"!

Comment: Most of rewrite rules are not _stored_ in `.htaccess`, but you probably can use that to knock out pretty permalinks from working altogether in such case to get to the site. To force WP to regenerate rules you can also erase `rewrite_rules` option in options table in database.